# unauthenticated: User cannot be authenticated with the token provided with Spatie Media Library Pro in Laravel 10 and Vue3

Tags: php, laravel

I've spent a few days on this but now I need help. I purchased Spatie's Media Library Pro to implement into my Laravel 10 project and since I am using Vue 3, I need to download the associated libraries from Spatie's private repo. In my Spatie account, it shows that `Access has been granted to these repos on GitHub spatie/laravel-medialibrary-pro`. I've followed all the documentation on this but every time I run `npm install @spatie/media-library-pro-styles @spatie/media-library-pro-vue3-attachment --save`, I get the following error:

```
hubmls git:(master) ✗ npm install @spatie/media-library-pro-styles @spatie/media-library-pro-vue3-attachment --save
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! 401 Unauthorized - GET https://npm.pkg.github.com/@spatie%2fmedia-library-pro-styles - unauthenticated: User cannot be authenticated with the token provided.
```

Here are the steps I followed and the files I set up per the documentation.

**Added to composer.json**

```
...
"repositories": [{
    "type": "composer",
    "url": "https://satis.spatie.be"
}],
...
```

**Created an auth.json file with the following**

```
{
    "http-basic": {
        "satis.spatie.be": {
            "username": "mySpatieAccountEmailAddress.com",
            "password": "mySpatieMediaProLicenseNumber"
        }
    }
}
```

I then added an `.npmrc` file and added the data as shown [here](https://spatie.be/docs/laravel-medialibrary/v9/handling-uploads-with-media-library-pro/installation#:%7E:text=%23-,%23,-REGISTERING%20WITH%20GITHUB) in the docs. But, I still get the same error.

I then did the next alternative per the docs and logged directly into npm:

```
npm login --registry=https://npm.pkg.github.com --scope=@spatie
```

I logged in using my GitHub username and my personal token and it successfully logged me in `Logged in to scope @spatie on https://npm.pkg.github.com/.`

I then ran the npm install again but received the same error.